# Why is the first false start allowed an exception while the second is not?

Tags: rules, speed-skating

The first skater to make a false start is pardoned. But the second skater, even if it is not the same person, is disqualified.

What is the logic behind that? Why, if I'm not at fault in the first false start, would I be disqualified if I provoke the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule was introduced in 2004 (it is referred to in [this interview](https://www.trouw.nl/home/sprintkampioen-van-velde-hekelt-nieuwe-startregel~a20a6904/) in 2004 as a 'new starting rule'), and it was said to be copied from track&field rules.

The reasoning behind it was simply to save time. If in a 500m competition, all riders would have one false start, there would be too much time in between the Zamboni cleaning breaks, and some riders would ride on bad ice. Additionally, it is easier to make a tournament planning if less time needs to be reserved for potential false starts.